# Set Values for dynamically generated input text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a `json` values in `Table2`. Which brings values based on data entered. The data is in below format.

```
"Table2":[{"SP_VENDOR_ID":94.0,"VENDORCODE":"V001","VENDORNAME":"Vendor 1","SP_VENDOR_START_DATE":"2017-12-04T00:00:00","SP_VENDOR_END_DATE":"2017-12-05T00:00:00"},{"SP_VENDOR_ID":95.0,"VENDORCODE":"V002","VENDORNAME":"Vendor 2","SP_VENDOR_START_DATE":"2017-12-06T00:00:00","SP_VENDOR_END_DATE":"2017-12-07T00:00:00"}],
```

Now I want to fill the above values in the below HTML which Is below

```
<div class="vendorDaterow">
    <div class="vendorName" id="dvVendorNameData1">
        <label>SP Vender Name</label><span>@*Shri Kamalkanth Co.*@<input type="text" value="" name="nmVendorData" id="txtVendorName1" /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="vendorFromDate">
        <label>From Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" value="" name="spFromDate" id="spFromDate1"/><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="vendorToDate">
        <label>To Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" value="" name="spToDate" id="spToDate1" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I tried with below code but not getting it done rightly.

```
var data = dataResponse;
var divData = $('.vendorDaterow');
$.each(data.Table2, function (i) {
    $.each(data.Table2[i], function (item, index) {
        if (item) {
            $(".vendorDaterow").append(divData);
            $(divData).addClass("vendorDaterow" + index);
            $(".vendorDaterow .vendorName:last").val(item.VENDORNAME);
            $(".vendorDaterow vendorFromDate:last").val(item.SP_VENDOR_START_DATE);
            $(".vendorDaterow .vendorToDate:last").val(item.SP_VENDOR_END_DATE);
        }

    });
});
```

Please suggest what is wrong here and how should I set it dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your code is written you will be repeatedly writing to all your elements with class .vendorDaterow

Below is an example of one possible solution . Avoid setting ID attributes in your repeated template, as the ID should be unique.

```js
var data = {"Table2":[{"SP_VENDOR_ID":94.0,"VENDORCODE":"V001","VENDORNAME":"Vendor 1","SP_VENDOR_START_DATE":"2017-12-04T00:00:00","SP_VENDOR_END_DATE":"2017-12-05T00:00:00"},{"SP_VENDOR_ID":95.0,"VENDORCODE":"V002","VENDORNAME":"Vendor 2","SP_VENDOR_START_DATE":"2017-12-06T00:00:00","SP_VENDOR_END_DATE":"2017-12-07T00:00:00"},{"SP_VENDOR_ID":95.0,"VENDORCODE":"V002","VENDORNAME":"Vendor 3","SP_VENDOR_START_DATE":"2017-12-06T00:00:00","SP_VENDOR_END_DATE":"2017-12-07T00:00:00"}]}

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  
  for(var i=1;i< data.Table2.length;i++){
    var newId = $(".vendorDaterow").length + 1
    var clonedHtml = $(".vendorDaterow:first").clone(true).addClass("vendorDaterow"+newId)
    clonedHtml.find(".vendorName input").prop("id","txtVendorName"+newId)
    clonedHtml.find(".vendorFromDate input").prop("id","spFromDate"+newId)
    clonedHtml.find(".vendorToDate input").prop("id","spToDate"+newId)
    $(".vendorDaterow:last").after(clonedHtml)
  }
   
  
  $.each(data.Table2, function(index, item) {
    $("#txtVendorName"+(index+1)).val(item.VENDORNAME);
    $("#spFromDate"+(index+1)).val(item.SP_VENDOR_START_DATE);
    $("#spToDate"+(index+1)).val(item.SP_VENDOR_END_DATE);
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <div class="vendorDaterow">
    <div class="vendorName" id="dvVendorNameData1">
      <label>SP Vender Name</label><span>@*Shri Kamalkanth Co.*@<input type="text" value="" name="nmVendorData" id="txtVendorName1"  /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="vendorFromDate">
      <label>From Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" value="" name="spFromDate" id="spFromDate1" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="vendorToDate">
      <label>To Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" value=""  id="spToDate1" name="spToDate1"    /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: where is `#vendorData` coming from ?

Comment: it's the wrapping div  `<div id="vendorData"></div>` that i added to HTML - it serves as a container for the dynamicaly generated rows.

Comment: also, `index` i always get it as undefined..why

Comment: You don't need to use two each loops - your example was wrong. Also , the parameters in my $.each loop are in order `index, item`,  in your code you have them reversed

Comment: its setting the data somewhere else but not where I wanted.

Comment: i provided a working example in my snippet - this should serve a as a starting point for your development, plus i pointed out the obvious mistakes you had in your code. It's up to you to implement your own solution, stackoverflow is not a coding service ;-)

Comment: Your code use .append() , which leads me to believe you are dynamicaly generating the elements before populating them. Can you explain what you mean by "not where i wanted" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161008/discussion-between-vvvv-and-mike-t).

Comment: mike_t: will u help me mate ? i m waiting

Comment: please help me out with this. if u want come on chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161008/discussion-between-vvvv-and-mike-t

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you will have only one text box inside each div then directly target the input element.

```
   $(".vendorDaterow .vendorName input").val(item.VENDORNAME);
   $(".vendorDaterow .vendorFromDate input").val(item.SP_VENDOR_START_DATE);
   $(".vendorDaterow .vendorToDate input").val(item.SP_VENDOR_END_DATE);
```

Comment: no, it wont be one. it will dynamically added. that is why I added in each loop

Comment: so you want to apply the last input element in each div. Or vendorDaterow will have many vendorName??

Comment: it can have many vendorName, depending upon the data which is coming fromm `Table2`

Comment: no its not working :(. `$(".vendorDaterow .vendorName input").val(item.VENDORNAME);` coming as undefined